# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup (x_n) =\min\{A \in \Bbb{R} : \forall\epsilon>0 \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \geq A+ \epsilon \} $ set is finite}

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Any tips solving this?
I think I need to firstly show that $\lim \sup x_n$ is element of the given min{...} set and secondly there are no smaller elements in the given set. 
Should I open the set with minimum definition? Or something like this:
$x_n > a+ \epsilon$ for finite number of sequence $x_n$ elements $\forall \epsilon$...
Thanks!
Edit: sequence $x_n$ is bounded.

Comment: What is your definition of $\limsup$? Please write it down, since this is a case of proceed by definition.

Comment: $ \overline{\lim_{n \to \infty}}x_n = \min\{A \in \Bbb{R} : \forall\epsilon>0 \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \geq A+ \epsilon \} $ set is finite} is written, but since sup is the same as that overlined so. I forgot to add, $x_n$ is a bounded sequence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Definition $1$ : $\limsup x_n$ is the supremum of the set of all (extended real) limit points of $x_n$ (and $-\infty$ if the set is empty). If real, then it is also a limit point, by the fact that the set of limit points of any set is closed.

If you do not know definition $1$ then proceed to definition $2$. You must be knowing at least one of these, and it is not difficult to show they are equivalent.

The boundedness of $x_n$ ensures that the limit supremum is a real number, hence we need not worry about infinities.

With this in mind, let us call the set $\{a \in\mathbb R : \forall \epsilon > 0 \mbox{,the set } \{n \in \mathbb N : x_n \geq a + \epsilon\} \mbox { is finite} \} = S$. We want to show that $\inf S \geq \limsup x_n$, and that $\limsup x_n \in S$. This will show that $\limsup x_n$ is the minimum of $S$, as desired.

---

Suppose $t < \limsup x_n$. Let $\epsilon = \frac{\limsup x_n - t}2$ . Then, take the subsequence $x_{n_k}$ which converges to $\limsup x_n$ : note that there exists $N$ such that $K > N $ implies  $x_{n_K} > t + \epsilon$ eventually,  since $t + \epsilon < \limsup x_n$, and $x_{n_k}$ is converging to the right hand side. This forces that $\{n \in \mathbb N : x_n \geq t+\epsilon\}$ is infinite, since $n_N, n_{N+1}$ etc. belong to this set.

Consequently, we have shown that $t \notin S$. In otherwise, for every $s \in S$, we must have $s \geq \limsup x_n$. This also gives $\inf S \geq \limsup x_n$.

---

We will now show that $\limsup x_n \in S$. Suppose not. Then, there exists $\epsilon > 0$  such that the set $\{n \in \mathbb N : x_n \geq \limsup x_n  + \epsilon\}$ is infinite. Now, take the elements of this set and order them like $m_1,m_2,...$. So we have $x_{m_i} \geq x_n + \epsilon$ for all $i$. The $x_{m_i}$ is a subsequence of $x_n$, hence bounded, but then any limit point of $x_{m_i}$ is a limit point of $x_n$, which must be strictly larger than $\limsup x_n$, since every element of $x_{m_i}$ is larger than $\limsup x_n + \epsilon$. This contradicts the definition of $\limsup x_n$, showing that $\limsup x_n \in S$.

Consequently, we have shown that $\limsup x_n \in S$ and every other element of $S$ is larger than $\limsup x_n$. It follows that $\limsup x_n = \min S$ as desired.

---

> Definition $2$ : $\limsup x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sup_{k \geq n} x_k)$.

Notation is the same as for definition $1$. We will use the same proof plan as for definition $1$ as well. Note that the sequence $\sup_{k \geq n} x_k$ is  a decreasing sequence, since the set over which supremum is being taken is getting smaller with increasing $n$.

---

Let $t \in S$. Then, fix $\epsilon > 0$. By definition of being in $S$, we see that $\{n \in \mathbb N : x_n \geq t + \epsilon\}$ is finite. Therefore, $t + \epsilon\geq \sup_{n \geq N+1} x_n$ for $N$ being the maximum of this set. But since $\sup_{k \geq N} x_k$ is decreasing, the right hand side is automatically greater than $\limsup x_n$, which is the limit of the decreasing sequence it is part of. So $t + \epsilon \geq \limsup x_n$, for all $\epsilon$, giving $t \geq \limsup x_n$.

---

Now, to show that $\limsup x_n \in S$, fix $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose $\{n : x_n \geq \limsup x_n + \epsilon\}$ is infinite. Order the elements of this set as $m_1,m_2,...$, then note that $\sup_{k \geq m_i} x_{k}\geq x_{m_i} \geq \limsup x_n + \epsilon$ for all $i$.  As a subsequence of the sequence $\sup_{k \geq n} x_k$ , this sequence must also converge to $\limsup x_n$, but it cannot be always greater than $\limsup x_n + \epsilon$, so there lies the contradiction.

Hence, we complete our proof in the same way.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such an explained answer! These two different ways really do help to understand the solution!

Comment: You are welcome. You may show your appreciation either through an up vote or through an acceptance of the answer, or may choose to wait for more answers. This will help close the question.